# ASP.NET MVC 5 And Web API 2 .NET requirement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

My host provider only supports .NET 4. Is it possible to run MVC 5 and Web API 2 in .NET 4 machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run MVC 5 application on .NET Framework 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385785/can-i-run-mvc-5-application-on-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: I saw that before post my question. That question was about Razor version but my question was about .net framework version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short Answer: No, you need .NET 4.5

Only if you add the dependencies:

- Razor v3.0+
- ASP.NET WebPages v3.0+

Answer (score 4):

No, ASP.NET Web API 2 requires .NET 4.5: http://forums.asp.net/t/1937143.aspx?Is+ASP+NET+MVC+5+and+Web+API+2+0+supported+on+NET+4+0+and+IIS6+ (scroll at the very bottom)