# HttpPostedFileBase not accepting file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest

I have a API method that needs to accept files. I am using Postman chrome plugin to call the api and attach a file.

I added API functionality to my MVC project after creating just an initial MVC web site. don't know if I missed some config but my other API calls work just this one not getting any files.

Here's the code

```
[Route("~/api/mediaitems/{token}/{eventId}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MediaItems(string token, int eventId, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string _targetFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"]);
            string _targetPath = Path.Combine(_targetFolder, Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName));
            upload.SaveAs(_targetPath);

            var mediaItem = new MediaItem
            {
                MediaFilePath = _targetPath,
                FileType = upload.FileName,
                EventId = eventId,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.Date
            };

            //Save mediaItem
            _repo.SaveMediaItem(mediaItem);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }           
    }

http://localhost:24727/api/mediaitems/12341254234/1
```

that's the URL and then I attach the .jpg to the postman body.
When I run the api request it never has the file therefore it can never save.

Comment: Can you try with a small file (a text file with a bunch of characters) and use chrome developer tools or fiddler to see and copy here the request body.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Is `MediaItems` invoked? which branch of `upload.ContentLength > 0` is executed?

Comment: I get a null reference exception on upload and when I add if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0) to if (upload.ContentLength > 0) it just skips and goes to return a bad request which means there is no HttpPostedFileBase

Comment: Can you describe the steps that you use in Postman to attach the file?

Comment: I insert the URL, select POST and then go to body where I added a file. tried .txt and .png

Comment: After you click body, do you select "binary"? or "form-data"?

Comment: there is a option to choose between a text and file, I chose file then a openfile dialog popsup

Comment: I was using form-data switched over to binary and get the following error.....message": "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
  "exceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpPostedFileBase' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```
[Route("~/api/mediaitems/{token}/{eventId}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MediaItems(string token, int eventId)
{
    byte[] data = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    //data will contain the file content, you can save it here

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Notice how I removed the `HttpPostedFileBase upload` parameter.

You can do some validation based on `this.Request.Content` if you want. For example, you might want to check the content length.

Comment: I do receive the data if I do it this way around but how will I go about saving it to a folder with a filename?

Answer (score 0):

Is that an `ApiController` ? There is not `HttpPostedFile` in Web API.

You have to use another approach: [How to post file to ASP.NET Web Api 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387764/how-to-post-file-to-asp-net-web-api-2/33388882)

Comment: It is a API controller, I have other API calls that work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help this...Add following to web.config. You must setup max accepted size of file in bytes: 15728640 = 15MB

```
<configuration>    
    <location path="Custommer/edit">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15728640"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```