# What happens my asp.net mvc Project is using mvc 5 and mvc 5 is not installed on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What happens my asp.net mvc Project is using mvc 5 and mvc 5 is not installed on the server?

Does it take the closest one, if 4 is installed it takes that insead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install MVC 5 via Nuget. That gives you the binaries and puts a reference in your project. Then when you deploy your application everything needed will be included, and there is no need to install anything on the server.

Comment: what is needed on the server, the right .net version, that is all?

Comment: Yes, you need .NET framework. As per this answer, you need version 4.5. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20386118/268091

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't take the closest one, unless you have a [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and this only works for lower versions not higher ones. You will need to reference mvc 5 in your project or put the assemblies in the GAC on the server.