# Changing MVC 5 and .NET target framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I was given the code to a MVC 5, .NET 4.5 project, problem is our server is too old to use .NET 4.5.

I've also read that MVC 5 cannot be run on .NET 4:
[Can I run MVC 5 application on .NET Framework 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385785/can-i-run-mvc-5-application-on-net-framework-4-0)

Is there any way, without restarting the entire project, to revert back to older versions? Also if this is much simpler than I anticipated, then can you direct me in the right direction?

Comment: I just know that .NET 4.0 can run on Windows Server 2003, but 4.5 cannot. If I can find the diagram that I found that explains that, I'll post it.

Comment: This what I was talking about.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, I see. What's the point to use OS which is 10 years old?

Comment: It's what I'm stuck with. haha Not my fault they haven't caught up yet.

Comment: Worth mentioning that support for 2003 runs out next year. We are currently upgrading. If you work for an enterprise they really should have a plan to upgrade too. [More info](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.appzero.com%2Fblog%2Fwindows-server-2003-end-life-coming-are-you-ready-survey&ei=q5t1VK-oMZLaatKegsgL&usg=AFQjCNFfF0Or0kN7q3rzJq-g0Qvx4nf_0g&sig2=I9vbl2cPp5bVL0bpFvDZjg&bvm=bv.80642063,d.d2s)

Comment: Welp, this luckily is a temporary position. But after talking with the dev team, I believe they are pushing for an upgrade as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it at MVC5 you will need .NET 4.5. You could perhaps create a new MVC 4 project instead and migrate the code over, which should not be too much trouble but you should check out what the differences are first and accommodate as necessary.

Comment: I will probably end up doing this, if there isn't any easier way. I was trying to avoid creating a new project.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you'll be able to avoid it but would be interested to hear about it if you can.