# Create MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I asked a question earlier about [Changing MVC 5 and .NET target framwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136376/changing-mvc-5-and-net-target-framwork) because the application I have will not work with Windows Server 2003 (they didn't tell me that). If you know a way to do this, so I can avoid what I'm about to ask, please let me know.

Anyways, I'm trying to create a MVC 4 web application using the newest from of Visual Studio 2013. In a new application I already changed the framework to .NET 4 but I only find MVC 5 listed when I try to create a new controller. 
I'm not really sure what I need to do, if I need to download a later version of Visual Studio or find a certain template.

Also, I learned how to create my web application using this tutorial, so maybe that will give you a better idea where I'm coming from, AKA I'm new at this stuff.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

Comment: Have you googled 'mvc4 server 2003'? loads of results.

Comment: I'm just lost when it comes to visual studio. What I'm gathering I think I'm going to have to get an older version of visual studio to create a MVC 4 application.

Comment: That might be an easier option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the MVC 4 Application (Based on ASP.Net 4, not 4.5) In the Visual Studio 2012 project types.  File -> New Project, Expand the Web node, Visual Studio 2012.  The Asp.net MVC 4 Web Application project template will create the correct controller templates.  It is not sufficient to create a standard MVC Application (which will be MVC 5) and then change the target framework.

Bear in mind, some examples you may find for MVC may not function exactly as advertised using the older framework type.

Comment: Ok thanks. I assumed I would have to get Visual Studio 2012. Man, I wish some of this stuff was more backward capable.

Comment: @momofierce What do you mean you wish it was more backwards compatible? You can make an MVC 4 app in Visual Studio 2013 by following Andrew's directions.

Comment: Oh I did not read that as carefully as I should have. Thank you for pointing that out @mason.