# MVC 5 server requirements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Just wondering what are the requirements of a server to be able to host and run MVC 5 applications.

I saw a post that said it was recommended that they use windows server 2012 R2

SO the questions I am asking is

what OS?
How much memory?
How many cores? is 2 preferred over 1? or does it make any difference?

Comment: .NET 4.5 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20386118/1464112

Comment: It depends on the application you're writing. The difference in system requirements for a native C/C++ CGI application vs. .NET might have mattered 10-12 years ago, but now every sever has gigabytes of RAM and a multicore processor so increased requirements for JIT, managed heap, etc are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific requirements on MVC 5 except for .NET 4.5 and IIS to be installed on the machine. MVC libraries do not even need to be installed on the server considering that MVC 5 apps can provide the relevant MVC 5 libraries during deployment.

Comment: maybe I should have asked what's the best requirements, as I need to build a server to host MVC 5 application and need to know if I should give the server 4GB or 8GB.. 1 core or 2 cores

Comment: Depends on how much volume you expect. If this is a tiny app with a very small number of users concurrently (< 5 or so), then 4GB with 2 cores (I wouldn't go under that) should be fine. Other factors are what else do you plan to host. Each MVC app as a best practice is usually hosted within an IIS environment in its own App Pool, so if you have a lot of these, 4GB can get pretty small with decent usage.

Comment: potentionally there will be around 70,000 users of the system.  But con-currently maybe 100

Comment: I would think 8gb ram and 2 cores could handle the loads. 4gb would probably work fine, but ram is so cheap I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: what about windows requirement for supporting .net framework and it's requirement?